# Pack UVs without rotating them?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I have an object with a UV unwrap, but there are overlapping parts. I want to pack islands to avoid any overlaps. However, the rotation of the islands matters due to using procedural textures. Pack Islands doesn't seem to give me any options, but is there a workaround or other tools that would let me stop overlapping UVs islands without rotating them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*UV Pack Islands* operator has an option allow/forbid island rotation. Just press <kbd>F6</kbd> after packing to adjust operator preferences like in *3D View* operators.

[image]

Comment: Gah! I assumed it had no operator because there wasn't one in the side panel where it usually is.